# Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to pass a list of String values from firestore table, but I am getting an exception `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

This is the function

```dart
  getLectureList(String userId) async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(userId).get();
    Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
    List<String> _lectureList =
        await data!['attendance']; //This line is kinda giving me trouble
    userInfo = FirestoreWrapper()
        .getStudentFromData(docId: currentUser(), rawData: data);
    return _lectureList;
  }
```

And this is the function where I am getting the exception thrown

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    lectureList = getLectureList(currentUser()); // Getting an exception here
    NearbyConn(context).searchDevices(devices: deviceList);
    super.initState();
  }
```

tried using await in the `getLectureList()` method but still getting the same problem

Comment: cast the value of the **attendance** field as a **List<String>** explicitly since originally it should be a **List<dynamic>**, so do **List<String> _lectureList = await data!['attendance'] as List<String>**.

Comment: What kind of data is returned by `docSnapshot.data()`? What's the type of `dynamic` in `Map<String, dynamic>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you `await` your data? You already got it.

```
List<String> _lectureList = data!['attendance'];
```

Please note that I don't know what your data structure looks like, so I cannot tell you if this is *correct*, I can only tell you that it is more correct than before, because the `await` did not belong there.

Comment: The data does not get loaded there.. that's why I keep the await keyword there, else I get an exception there.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about that exception then.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception here `lectureList = getLectureList(currentUser());` because the the parameter required by the `getLectureList()` method is the userId which is a string. I do not know what `currentUser()` return but I'm assuming it's the userId that you need when calling the `getLectureList()` method. Based on the error, it looks like `currentUser()` is an async method that returns a future after some time.

You're not awaiting that future. You shouldn't make the `initState()` method async so move the code block out of it into a separate method and then call it from `initState()`.

Something like this,

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getData();
  }

  void _getData() async {
    lectureList =
        getLectureList(await currentUser()); 
    NearbyConn(context).searchDevices(devices: deviceList);
  }
```

or

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getData();
  }

  void _getData() async {
    String _userID = await currentUser();
    lectureList = getLectureList(_userID);
    NearbyConn(context).searchDevices(devices: deviceList);
  }
```

Which I recommend so you can see all the parts.

Making your method parameters required named parameters also help you to easily see what is needed to pass to a function/class/.

Eg.

```
   getLectureList({required String userId}){
      ...
    }
```

Your IDE will alert you on the type of object the function requires and it makes things clearer.

Ultimately, I think typing your classes makes it so much more easier to fetch data from fireStore [Typing CollectionReference and DocumentReference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference)

This way you can easily do this,

```
final moviesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').withConverter<Movie>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
    );
```

and get your data this way,

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Obtain science-fiction movies
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Movie>> movies = await moviesRef
      .where('genre', isEqualTo: 'Sci-fi')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs);

  // Add a movie
  await moviesRef.add(
    Movie(
      title: 'Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV)',
      genre: 'Sci-fi'
    ),
  );

  // Get a movie with the id 42
  Movie movie42 = await moviesRef.doc('42').get().then((snapshot) => snapshot.data()!);
}
```

Keeps everything dry and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

```
< The data comes to list format thats why showing the exception of datatype > 

 List<String> lectureList = await getLectureList(currentUser());  // use 


  Future<List<String>> getLectureList(String userId) async {
      - your code -
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of
List _lectureList =
await data!['attendance'];

Try this
_lectureList = await data![] As List